# Populating data from two different url in a backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

I have a `Marionette.LayoutView` which calls a backbone collection and fetches the data and renders based on response. Now the issue that I am facing is, this collection needs to get data from two different endpoints, both should be independent, and then return the combined result. Below is my code:

My `Marionette.LayoutView`

```
var View = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

    template: _.template(some.html),

    regions: {
        div1: '[data-region="div1"]',
        div2: '[data-region="div2"]',
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new MovieCollection();
    },

    onRender: function () {
        if (this.collection.length) {
            this.div1.show(new TopMoviesByLikesView({
                collection: this.collection,
                movieCount: 10,
            }));

            this.div2.show(new TopMovieByRatingsView({
                collection: this.collection,
                movieCount: 10,
            }));
        }
    },

});

module.exports = AsyncView.extend({
    ViewConstructor: View,
});
```

My `Collection`

```
module.exports = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: TopMovieModel,

    initialize: function (response) {
        let movieCollection = [];
            let movieSourceOne = new TopMovieFromSourceOne();
            movieSourceOne.fetch({
                success: function (collection, response) {
                    movieCollection = [...movieCollection, ...response.data];
                },
                error: function (collection, response, options) {
                    console.info('~ Response::ERROR', collection, response, options);
                }
            });
        let movieSourceTwo = new movieSourceTwo();
        movieSourceTwo.fetch({
            success: function (collection, response, options) {
                movieCollection = [...movieCollection, ...response.data];
            },
            error: function(collection, response, options) {
                console.info('~ Response::ERROR', collection, response, options);
            }
        });
        this.collection = movieCollection;
    },
```

The error I get is `A “url” property or function must be specified` is there a way where I can do this without using a url in backbone collection? Note: I want to keep two endpoints independent since I don't want the collection to fail if primary API fails.

Comment: You want to keep both collections from your example?

Comment: Yes @LeshaOgonkov, since I will be filtering based on ratings and likes I need both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that error with `url`, you should override your `fetch` method, to call both collections `fetch` instead.

```js
function promisifyFetch(collection) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    collection.fetch({
      success() {
        resolve(collection);
      },

      error() {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

module.exports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: TopMovieModel,

  initialize() {
    this.movieSourceOne = new TopMovieFromSourceOne();
    this.movieSourceTwo = new movieSourceTwo();
  },

  fetch(options) {
    return Promise.all([
      promisifyFetch(this.movieSourceOne),
      promisifyFetch(this.movieSourceTwo)
    ]).then(([one, two]) => {
      const response = [
        ...one.toJSON(),
        ...two.toJSON()
      ];

      this.set(response, options);
      this.trigger('sync', this, response, options);
    });
  }
});
```

You probably want to handle errors here aswell.

Comment: Hey thanks, I kind of got the idea of overriding the fetch method, let me try out this solution and see if this works for me.

Comment: thanks @lesha-ogonkov, with a bit of few twist and your solution I was able to finally figure out my solution.